# Return different number of columns in results set

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am not very experienced with if statements so I need some help based on the following scenario.

I need to return a number of columns from TABLE_A as a result set where the number of columns returned is based on a setting in another table, say, TABLE_B.LEVEL.  For example, TABLE_B.LEVEL may be set at 3, so the result set needs to incorporate (3 - 1)  columns from TABLE_A.  Fortunately the columns headings within TABLE_A contain values similar to the following: STLEVEL01, STLEVEL02, STLEVEL03 etc. up to STLEVEL09.

So in my example, if TABLE_B.LEVEL = 3 then return STLEVEL01, STLEVEL02

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this bit being called through a stored procedure?

Comment: Unfortunately not at this stage, the query is embedded.  Having it being called through a stored procedure makes sense but unfortunately time is of the essence at the moment as I don't have time to create and test a new stored procedure.  Point taken though.

Comment: Seems like the easiest way would be to just bring all of the columns back and filter them out in code.  Otherwise you're sql statement is going to be pretty big.

Comment: Scratch that, you'll likely need 2 calls.  The first to get the `LEVEL`, then build some dynamic sql that queries just what you want.

Comment: You may be right, was hoping to be able to contain it in a query but can't find anything anywhere.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: You would need dynamic sql to do this and won't get an answer unless you post your data model in detail.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  If you can explain what functionality you're trying to achieve, we may be able to suggest a cleaner alternative to this multi-column solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using dynamic SQL - though I'd recommend rethinking your solution as returning different numbers of columns from a statement feels like a design flaw.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

;with cte as
(
    select top 1 cast('select STLEVEL01 ' as nvarchar(max)) [sql], 0 [level], [level] [lastColumn]
    from table_b 

    union all

    select [sql] + ', STLEVEL0' + CAST([level]+1 as nvarchar(max)), [level]+1, [lastColumn]
    from cte
    where [level] < [lastColumn]
)
select @sql = [sql] + ' from table_a'
from cte
where [level] = [lastColumn]

exec(@sql)
```